# IN SQL operator

Tags: sql

How can I modify this query?

```
SELECT column_a,  
  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_b) 
    FROM table_b 
    WHERE column_b IN (main_tbl.column_a) ) AS alias_a   
FROM table_a main_tbl
```

Assuming that column_a has a value of 1,2,3.

The output of the above query is similar to this:

```
SELECT column_a,  
  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_b) 
    FROM table_b 
    WHERE column_b IN ('1,2,3') ) AS alias_a   
FROM table_a main_tbl
```

What I need is:

```
SELECT column_a,  
  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_b) 
    FROM table_b 
    WHERE column_b IN (1,2,3) ) AS alias_a   
FROM table_a main_tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should **strongly** consider revising your table structure. I can't see any reason to store a list of integers as a string in a relational database, it defeats the point of a relational database.

However you could get around this by using `LIKE`.

```
SELECT column_a,  
  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_b) 
    FROM table_b 
    WHERE CONCAT(',', main_tbl.column_a, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', column_b, ',%') ) AS alias_a   
FROM table_a main_tbl
```

Not ideal, but it works. Example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a88ef/3)